# Break from loop after given a number

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am having issue to have my "break loop" to work, it doesn't throw any error so I can't even see what's happening. It is the option 3 when I tell the script to start blinking my LED. Originally I was looking into some ways if there is a way to run your loop and go back to your MainMenu while the loop is still running, But that wasn't the options, so I wanted to try something similar to use "for number in range(10):"

```
def loop():
    while True:
        os.system('clear')
        print
        print ('1. ON')
        print ('2. OFF')
        print ('3. Blink')
        print
        choice = int(raw_input('1-[ON], 2-[OFF]: '))
        if choice == 1:
            print
            print ('Turning ON')
            GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.LOW)  # Led ON
        elif choice == 2:
            print
            print ('Turning OFF')
            GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.HIGH)  # Led OFF
        elif choice == 3:
            number = 0
            for number in range(10):
               number = number + 1
               if number == 5:
                  break
                  GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.LOW + str(number))  # Led ON
                  time.sleep(0.05)
                  GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.HIGH + str(number))  # Led OFF
                  time.sleep(0.05)
               #print ('Number is ' + str(number))
```

this example works fine:

```
    number = 0

for number in range(10):
   number = number + 1

   if number == 5:
      break    # break here

   print('Number is ' + str(number))

print('Out of loop')
```

Output:

```
Number is 1
Number is 2
Number is 3
Number is 4
Out of loop
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to write commands *after* you `break`. Your question is not clear - try to explain *what* do you want to achieve not *how* you're trying to do so.

Comment: Why are you using `number = number + 1` within a range loop?

Comment: Nothing about this makes any sense. Can you describe clearly what it's supposed to do? The blink option does nothing until it reaches 5, and then it does even more nothing, but in no case does it blink anything.

Comment: What is "MainMenu"?

Comment: Sorry for my english. I am trying to choose option 3, and have the loop run 5 times, and then exit or go back to main menu

Comment: Your loop runs 10 times. Use `range(5)` if you want 5 times... Should be self-explanatory

Comment: 5 times or 10 times, even if I place break on the bottom of the loop it wont run

Comment: `for _ in range(5)`

Comment: Don't try to modify a loop variable manually while inside the loop.  Choose another variable name if you feel you must have two variables for some reason.  And once you execute the `break`, the loop ends, so that code that follows your `break` is unreachable and serves no purpose.

Comment: edited my post.

Comment: Do you want the led to blink 5 times? Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to toggle the light if number == 5

> ```
>         elif choice == 3:
>            for number in range(0,5):
>               GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.LOW + str(number))  # Led ON
>                  time.sleep(0.05)
>                  GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.HIGH + str(number))  # Led OFF
>                  time.sleep(0.05)
>            #print ('Number is ' + str(number)) #will be 4, went 5 times
> ```

Comment: I think he wants the led to blink 5 times? Not 100% sure as the question does not make much sense.

Comment: Yes I want the led blink (loop) 5 times

Answer (score -2):

I dont know if this will help at all, but maybe try using quit or a while loop instead like:

when number == 5:
quit (This will make your program stop)

However, even if you use break, it doesn't make sense to write code after it, so maybe comment your code that goes after it out and see if it works.